# SSHFS not connecting at login using .profile - connection reset by peer

Tags: login, automount, .profile, sshfs

I'm trying to create an sshfs connection when I login, so I have added a call to a script within the ~/.profile which runs the sshfs command.

Here's the script that is called:

```
!/bin/bash
sshfs jason@192.168.0.6:/media/media/videos/ /home/jason/Desktop/sftpx8dtl/ -p 50505 -o IdentityFile=/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I login, I get a box that tells me that the connection has been reset by the peer.

If I then immediately open a terminal and run the script above manually, it works fine.

Is there some other program that needs to be running prior to the commands in ~/.profile?

I don't think there's anything wrong with the command itself since it works fine when I run it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a ~/.ssh/config entry set up that includes the user, host, port, and identity file which I use for regular ssh, and I tried using that as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what desktop session are you using? is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-32
Desktop is Lubuntu
I don't believe it's encrypted.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. @wedsa5 please update with any solution you found.

Comment: @Sqerstet I had actually put a sleep 1 command just before calling the script. but I believe the best way to always mount the sshfs is to add it to your /etc/fstab file so it mounts at boot

Comment: @wedsa5 Thanks, useful.